# How to include the DOMAIN\ in the name autofilled field when connecting to a Samba share from Finder?

Tags: finder, keychain, mount, smb

I have a samba folder saved on my Finder Favourites.  The Account field for the associated server in Keychain includes the domain (so,DOMAIN\USERNAME ) but when I click to connect and the Account and Password are autofilled, the DOMAIN\ isn't included and I have to manually type it in every time.  How do I force the DOMAIN\ to be included?

Answer (score 2):

What works is to specify the DOMAIN by connecting via *Go → Connect to Server*  (via this [crazy old site](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031203172256827)).

```
smb://DOMAIN;User@machine.somewhere.com/Share
```

You can mark this as a favorite in the “connect” dialog as well as add the resulting shared folder to Finder Sidebar or even drag it into startup items system preference pane.